# Points Outside Linear Regression Confidence Band

Tags: regression, confidence-interval, prediction-interval

I have done a linear regression of predicted measurements (of my model) vs. observed measurements and plotted the confidence band. Can I draw any conclusions about the points that lie outside the band?

If I am interpreting confidence bands correctly, if a point does not lie within the confidence band it means that there is 95% chance that its not within the range of the mean predicted value for that specific $x$ value (observed measurement) and nothing else (I cannot say anymore).

Comment: A confidence interval isn't an interval for a point. Keep in mind the distinction between a confidence interval for the mean and a prediction interval for an observation. e.g. see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/225652/prediction-interval-vs-confidence-interval-in-linear-regression-analysis). In addition, even if every assumption was exactly correct, you'd still expect some points outside a prediction interval. [Of course if you're looking at points you used in the fitting an appropriate interval would be different from a PI, and its meaning is somewhat trickier.]

Answer (score 5):

No, you essentially cannot infer anything from a data point lying outside the *confidence* band.

I think your interpretation of the confidence and the prediction bands may be off.

- The 95% *confidence* band is a band that contains the *true unknown mean* response for a particular predictor value 95% of the time if you were to repeat your experiment many, many times.
- The 95% *prediction* band is a band that contains 95% of *future observable realizations* if you were to repeat your experiment many, many times.

Note the difference: the confidence band applies to unobservable parameter estimates, the prediction band to observables. The confidence band only includes uncertainty in estimating the mean; the prediction band includes both this uncertainty and residual variation *around* this mean. You may want to look at the tag wikis for [confidence-interval](/questions/tagged/confidence-interval) and [prediction-interval](/questions/tagged/prediction-interval).

Here is an illustration. Note how the *confidence* band gets smaller as we increase the number $n$ of observations, because we can estimate the mean more and more precisely. Conversely, the *prediction* band does get smaller, but not so much, because while the uncertainty around estimating the mean gets smaller, the residual variation stays the same.

[image: confidence vs prediction]

```
opar <- par(mfrow=c(2,2))
    for ( nn in c(20,80) ) {
        set.seed(1)

        xx <- sort(runif(nn,-1,1))
        yy <- 0.5*xx+0.2*rnorm(nn)
        model <- lm(yy~xx)
        conf <- predict(model,interval="confidence")
        pred <- predict(model,interval="prediction")

        plot(xx,yy,type="n",ylim=c(-1,1),main=paste(nn,"data points, with confidence band"))
        polygon(c(xx,rev(xx)),c(conf[,"lwr"],rev(conf[,"upr"])),col="lightgrey",border=NA)
        abline(model)
        points(xx,yy,pch=19)

        plot(xx,yy,type="n",ylim=c(-1,1),main=paste(nn,"data points, with prediction band"))
        polygon(c(xx,rev(xx)),c(pred[,"lwr"],rev(pred[,"upr"])),col="darkgrey",border=NA)
        abline(model)
        points(xx,yy,pch=19)
    }
par(opar)
```

(Note that you'd typically not use a prediction interval for those observations you trained your model on, and R rightly complains about this. Conversely, looking at the confidence interval in-sample makes perfect sense.)

Comment: Maybe my misunderstanding, but your description of a prediction interval doesn't seem correct to me. To simplify what I mean, consider a single estimation at a particular x, as opposed to the full regression band. My understanding of a prediction interval is that if you do your experiment, form your interval, then make a single subsequent observation, 95 % of these will be within the interval - when the whole process is repeated. Which is not quite the same as saying that 95 % of all subsequent observations will be in the interval - the latter is the definition of a tolerance interval.