# Check if observed data lies outside predicted distribution

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

I am using a linear regression to model the distribution of my data. For the data point I have visualized the standard deviation.
It looks like this:
The red line is the linear regression I have fitted to the data. the yellow line is the 95% confidence interval.

[image]

My question now is, if there is a way to determine which of my data points differ significantly from the predicted linear regression.

Comment: Could you explain what the three colored lines represent?

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: What you seem to have drawn is the regression line with a confidence interval for the regression. It rather suggests that the errors in the dependent variable is greater than you have shown. What you may want to spot outliers is a [prediction interval](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/225652/prediction-interval-vs-confidence-interval-in-linear-regression-analysis) or [prediction band](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/280268/points-outside-linear-regression-confidence-band)

Comment: You should check if what you have drawn is *confidence* intervals or *prediction* intervals!